# How can I get chain id explorer?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am building a dApp with ethersjs and metamask and everything works fine however, I want to be able to get the chain explorer so users can check the details of their transaction.
At the moment, `new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).network` gives me the chain ID but not the block explorer URL as in `https://goerli.etherscan.io/` for goerli test net.
How can I get the block explorer of any chain ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethers doesn't have information about the block explorers, they're external services. But you can use this library from metamask: https://github.com/MetaMask/etherscan-link it will generate a block explorer url from a given chainId.

The other option is to hardcode a map of chainIds to block explorer URLs, which may sound like a bad idea but at least you're in control of where you're pointing your users towards, instead of passing on that responsibility to another library

Comment: Thank you. I think Metamask hardcodes their or not?

Comment: @user18039014 yes, they're hardcoded in their repo, the wagmi library for react has the block explorer urls hardcoded as well. 
Etherscan is not a part of the blockchain, it's just a website, so I don't think there's a better way to do it at this time

Answer (score 0):

I think with ethers v6 which was published a few days ago you can get specific data about Block and its transactions.

```
import { BrowserProvider ,Block} from "ethers";

const providerr = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
```

this is `Block constructor sign`

```
constructor(block: BlockParams, provider: Provider) {}
```

this is `BlockParams`

```
export interface BlockParams {
    hash?: null | string;

    number: number;
    timestamp: number;

    parentHash: string;

    nonce: string;
    difficulty: bigint;

    gasLimit: bigint;
    gasUsed: bigint;

    miner: string;
    extraData: string;

    baseFeePerGas: null | bigint;

    transactions: ReadonlyArray<string | TransactionResponseParams>;
};
```

once you created a Block instance, you can access all the methods. Check the source code of `Block` class in node_modules

Comment: I am not looking for the block information. Just the block explorer url